# How to casually say "on three" in French? Which preposition to use?

Tags: prépositions, nombres

> Bon, **à trois** je pars à gauche, et toi à droite.

I wonder if this phrasing sounds good enough? Saying "***à*** trois" rather than"***sur*** trois"? Basically, I wanted to express the idea of "*On my mark/count, three, two, one, go*".

In German, for instance, you say "*Okay, **auf drei**. Ich links, du rechts*", with "auf" corresponding to "sur". In Italian, on the other hand, it would be "*allora **al mio tre***", with "al" being interpreted as both "à" and "sur".

How do French speakers commonly express this idea? Would you use some other phrase?

Answer (score 4):

We never say <s>sur trois</s>, ***à trois*** is perfectly idiomatic here.

When counting down (actually up), like with "ready, set, go", we say:

> À la une, à la deux, à la trois !

When really counting down, we use the numbers alone:

> Trois, deux, un, zéro !

Comment: What? Counting up? Interesting find! Incidentally, in English, it could also be "on the count of three". In French, is "à trois" almost exclusively used?

Comment: Yes, *à un, à deux, à trois, à dix...*